# env.NODE_ENV always returns the default value in REACT APP

Tags: node.js, reactjs, frontend

Try 1:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "set REACT_APP_STAGE=dev && react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
}
```

Try 2:

```
"scripts": 
"start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=dev&&react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test"
}

//Also tried with and without space
```

Script,

```
export const configuration = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? prod
    : dev;
```

> - Always returns development locally and production in pipeline

I know there are so many question I have tried all the combination it never helped.

Comment: [*"**You cannot override `NODE_ENV` manually.**"*](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables)

Comment: Try to create a .env file in root directory and change NODE_ENV = something , I hope this could help.